# syntax errors for clicklistener

Tags: android, button, syntax

Okay friends. So I've got my app doing some basic functionality and am quite pleased with myself. My next goal was to set up a button and alternate activity/layout. I got the intent to move on to the activity and it works fine outside of the button code. However when merging into the button code I am riddled with syntax error. What am I doing wrong for the button?

.java

```
package com.eai.vgp;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         Button op1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.op1);

            op1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OptionsActivity.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the imports, your code won't compile without them. Use Ctrl+Shift+O in Eclipse to organize imports.

Comment: @Egor good tip. It's not a habit YET but I did remember this time. I appreciate the backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
op1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), OptionsActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToNextActivity);
   }
});
```

You need to have both a semicolon at the end of your anonymous class declaration and you need to put the code that starts and makes your Activity in the overriden `onClick()`. I also changed your intent to use the View's Context, just for cleaner code.

Comment: Naturally I'm just sloppy with code. I kept rearranging my code I probably overwrote some of it. -_- I'm gonna research into the v.getContext() for a better understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: @EricAnthony I use `v.getContext()` in my answers since people have a hard time understanding how to get a `Context` instance when inside an anonymous inner class (since they're used to using `this`, which now will refer to the inner class instance, which isn't a `Context`). Basically, every View, when made, gets a Context assigned. This method just retrieves that Context.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
op1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OptionsActivity.class);
        startActivity(goToNextActivity);
    }
});
```

You were missing the `);` required to complete the statement, and didn't have an `onClick()` method in place.

Also, you'll want to change `getApplicationContext()` to `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: Also a good answer. Thanks for the help. I'm still learning and I usually miss the small things.